# What was the most measurably unpopular law ever passed in USA?

Tags: united-states, democracy

Theoretically, in a democracy, laws that pass are - or should be, in theory - at least somewhat popular.

In a representative democracy, they may be less so (by design).

What was the law that was the least popular that ever passed US Congress (and was signed by President)?

When I say "popular" I mean actually measurable popularity among the people, ideally based on well-methodological polling as determined by either overall population or likely voters. Out of scope: measurement among vocal but less numerous opposition or congresspeople who voted for the law.

Additionally, the popularity measure must be right before the law is passed (e.g. presumably, Prohibition would be rather unpopular if polled today, doesn't mean it wasn't popular when passed).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation about various laws which might be contenders for this title has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62582/discussion-on-question-by-user4012-what-was-the-most-measurably-unpopular-law-ev).

Comment: Please stop posting comments which suggest laws which might be the correct answer. If you want to make guesses, use the chatroom linked above. If you want to answer the question, post a proper answer.

Comment: @Philipp: Well, you see what good your deletion of comments has done.  Four months and no answers :-)